# My pandas logic doesn't seem to result what I want, no matter how many tests and changes I make

Tags: python, c#, pandas

```
df['col1'] = df.loc[((df['NGPC PT'] > 1) | ((df['SC'] < 2)& (df['SC'] > 5)) & ((df['NGPC PT'] >4) & (df['NGPC PT'] <7))),'RULE OF NGPC'] ='SO'
```

Basically there are two values this is supposed to give OBS and SO, OBS is what is the standard value for col1 and whenever the values don't meet the below requirements they change to SO.

*note the below reqs are in C#:

```
 d["RULE OF NGPC"] = (v["PT"].Equals("5") || v["PT"].Equals("6")) ? "OBS" : "SO";
                int COUNT = 0;
                if(v["PT"].Equals("1"))
                {
                    if ((v["SC"].Equals("2"))&&(COUNT==0))
                    {
                        COUNT = COUNT + 1;
                        d["RULE OF NGPC"] = (v["PT"].Equals("1") && v["SC"].Equals("2")) ? "OBS" : "SO";
                    }
                    if ((v["SC"].Equals("3")) && (COUNT == 0))
                    {
                        COUNT = COUNT + 1;
                        d["RULE OF NGPC"] = (v["PT"].Equals("1") && v["SC"].Equals("3")) ? "OBS" : "SO";
                       
                    }
                    if ((v["SC"].Equals("4")) && (COUNT == 0))
                    {
                        COUNT = COUNT + 1;
                        d["RULE OF NGPC"] = (v["PT"].Equals("1") && v["SC"].Equals("4")) ? "OBS" : "SO";
                       
                    }
                    if ((v["SC"].Equals("5")) && (COUNT == 0))
                    {
                        COUNT = COUNT + 1;
                        d["RULE OF NGPC"] = (v["PT"].Equals("1") && v["SC"].Equals("5")) ? "OBS" : "SO";
                     
                    }
                   

                }


                d["NGPC PT"] = v["PT"];
                d["SC"] = v["SC"];
```

The code in C# above is not mine, I am trying to convert it to python.

Comment: For logic operations, python accepts "||" or "or", and "&&" or "and".

Comment: Typo in `df['col1]`, should be `df['col1']`

Comment: not for pandas operations @A.M. Ducu

Comment: That was a typo when I was adding the code here still no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you first initialize the column with 'OBS', then replace the values based on your conditions:

```
df['output'] = 'OBS'
df.loc[((df['NGPC PT'] > 1) | ((df['SC'] < 2)& (df['SC'] > 5)) & ((df['NGPC PT'] >4) & (df['NGPC PT'] <7))),'output'] = 'SO'
```

This may work if none of the conditions in the expression are wrong.

Comment: this did not work, it pretty resulted the same.

Comment: I did set the values to OBS